# Notation R/qR meaning

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Suppose $R$ is defined as $\mathbb{Z}[x]/f(x)$ where $f(x)=x^3+1$. From what I understand the result is the class of elements from the Euclidean division by $f(x)$. But what does $R_q=R/qR$ mean? Is it simply the polynomial module $q$, the same as $\mathbb{Z}_q[x]/f(x)$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, $q$ is an integer.

The short answer is 'yes', although just be careful because $f(x)$ is not an element in $\mathbb Z_q[x]$. However, there is a natural map from $\mathbb Z[x] \to \mathbb Z_q[x]$ and so we can easily think of integer polynomials as elements in $\mathbb Z_q[x]$.

Note that $qR$ is an ideal of $R$. So we can form the quotient $R/qR$. That is what $R/qR$ is by definition.

Consider the surjective map $\mathbb Z[x] \to \mathbb Z[x]/(f(x)) = R  \to R/ qR$.

The kernel of this composition is exactly the ideal $(q, f(x))$ in $\mathbb Z[x]$. So $R/qR$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z[x]/(q,f(x))$.

The surjective map $\mathbb Z_q[x] = \mathbb Z[x]/q\mathbb Z[x] \to \mathbb Z[x]/(q,f(x))$ has kernel $(\overline f(x))$, where $\overline f$ is the imagine in $\mathbb Z_q[x]$ of $f$.

So $\mathbb Z_q[x]/(\overline f(x)) \cong \mathbb Z[x]/(q,f(x)) \cong R/qR$.